# Why is the Git version I install with Homebrew different from the version on the website?

Tags: git, terminal, installation, homebrew

When I installed Git with Homebrew it shows as version 1.8.5.2 but on the website the download is for 2.0.1.

Why is Homebrew installing a different version of Git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the pre-installed git path (`/usr/bin/git`) isn't before the one installed by brew (`/usr/local/bin/git`).

Check if `/usr/local/bin/git --version` returns the expected version.
Or `/usr/local/git/bin/git --version`.

See more at:

- "[Homebrew installation of git won't take precedence over system version (in /usr/bin/)](https://superuser.com/q/498767/141)"
- "[How to properly update git on mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/93002)"
- "[Which Git? How to Keep Git Up To Date on Mac](http://blog.grayghostvisuals.com/git/how-to-keep-git-updated/)"

  ```
  export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH 
  brew install git
  brew upgrade git
  ```