# Updating Git from Version 1.9.0 to 2.2.1

Tags: macos, git

My console recently made me aware that the git version I have installed on my Mac has various security flaws and I was advised to upgrade.

I don't know how to use homebrew so I have gone for an easier option. I was recommended to download the following installed by **git-scm.com**

http://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/?source=typ_redirect

I have installed the package but my terminal still shows:

```
MacBook-Pro-3:~ mruser$ git --version
git version 1.9.0
MacBook-Pro-3:~ mruser$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git
```

I have noticed that this version is in the /bin/ folder, which may be the problem? Since the other version installs in the /local/ folder.

How do I remove the old git version 1.9.0 so I can successfully install the new version? (without affecting any of the applications I'm working on)

Thanks for having a look and for any input!

Comment: You should learn how to use Homebrew.  It's not difficult; in this case it would have been `brew update; brew upgrade git`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth it's that simple? Just install Homebrew and then run those commands in the console?

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24968795/6309

Comment: @VonC that was absolutely perfect, hats off to you sir!

Answer (score 2):

The Git in `/usr/local` (presumably 1.9.0) is *shadowing* the new release.  To determine which program to use, your shell looks through a list of directories stored in your PATH environment variable.  You can see it with `echo $PATH`.  Generally `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/usr/bin` so you can use newer versions of software without overwriting the system supplied ones.

You need to remove the old version from `/usr/local`.  How you do this depends on where you got Git 1.9.0.  If it has an uninstaller, use it.  If it doesn't, you can look through `/usr/local` and delete anything with "git" in it, that will *probably* be safe.

In the future, use a package manager like [Homebrew](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http%3A%2F%2Fbrew.sh%2F) or [Macports](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.macports.org%2F).  They will track what you have installed and make it much easier to upgrade them.